# Google Sheet & App Script : how to get image from a link preview?

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, import, rss

I am trying to reproduce a **RSS reader** like [Feedly](https://feedly.com/) with **Google Sheet** and displaying with [**Glide**](https://www.glideapps.com/) as an app on my mobile phone.

Everything's fine with `IMPORTFEED()` function with titles, description, URL.
But it seems this function **doesn't allow pictures** to be displayed even if they are in the feed (which is not all the time).

So I am looking for a way to **extract the main image from a blog post**... the one displayed when you hover on a link in a Google Sheet cell.
I would like to get the link of that image displayed in the link preview and put that link in another cell.

Here is an example:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/31CPl.png]

I tried `IMAGE()`
and also `IMPORTXML` when there is an image in the RSS feeds (but not all of them do... so I stopped)

*Is it possible in Google Sheet to get the main image from the one displayed in the link preview ?*

For instance, one of the blog I want to extract the main picture of a blog article would be **Creajv** (URL : https://creajv.com/ ; Feed : https://creajv.com/feed/)

So the `IMPORTFEED()` function I did in Google Sheets was :

```
=IMPORTFEED("https://creajv.com/feed/";"items";FALSE;3)
```

Which stands for :

- `=IMPORFEED(...)` the function to import feeds from an URL
- `"items"` the way to pull every data there is in the feed (you can use other parameters and can see all the possibilities on the [GoogleFormulas documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093337))
- `FALSE` because I don't want the headers to be included
- and the number `3` because I want only the last 3 results displayed.

And it displays perfectly : *author, description, URL, date*

But I did a little digging in Google and found that basically `IMPORTFEED()` cannot get images from feeds, even if it is added by the author of the blog (he has to add a feature to do it).

So I am now trying to see if there is **another way** which is not `IMPORTFEED()` to get every time the main image of a blog post.
And I saw Google Sheet is able to pull instantly it when I copy paste the URL of a blog article within a cell for instance for **Creajv** :

[Print screen of the image I get when I click in the cell which contains the post URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtPK0.png)

So my thoughts would be that I can pull *the author, date, description etc. with IMPORTFEED* (which works perfectly every time) and **use a formula on the cell with the URL to get in another cell the URL of the picture** pulled from the one in the link preview.

Two other possibilities might also be with **Google App Script** :

- creating with the App Script a custom function
- or creating a script pulling the image in a cell every time a new row is added via the `IMPORTFEED()` function.

Comment: Which blog are you trying to get the data from? Also, can you show `IMPORTFEED()` you tried?

Comment: Hi @Jescanellas, I edited my previous post with additional info to answer your question :)

Answer (score 0):

**Functions only, as Apps Script doesn't run on mobile Apps**

How about this solution? I checked the [website](https://creajv.com/2020/11/08/concours-de-level-design-avec-unreal-engine/)  and inspected the image from the thumbnail.
Luckily, the structure is simple:

```
<div class="article-image">
   <img src="https://creajv.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/HighresScreenshot00000.png" alt="Concours de Level Design avec Unreal Engine, du 11/11 au 05/12/2020">
</div>
```

You can get the url with [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en), and apply [IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en) to it:

`=IMAGE(ImportXml("https://creajv.com/2020/11/08/concours-de-level-design-avec-unreal-engine/", "//div[@class='article-image']//img/@src"))`

Since you are already retrieving the post url with your previous formula, change the source url by the correspondent cell:

`=IMAGE(ImportXml(C1, "//div[@class='article-image']//img/@src"))`

For example:
[image]

Comment: It is indeed a solution I already tried and here are the reasons why I didn't choose to stay with it :
(1) you would have to inspect the structure of the blog every time... And XML isn't easy for beginners like me... I tried for ages and no blog are with the same architecture
(2) it seems Google Sheet doesn't allow too many ImportXML... I already have a few and a few cells began to display "...loading" (for ages) telling me "to remove some XML from the sheet"
(3) IMPORTXML take some time to retrieve the info and some time break or don't display quick enough for me to use in mobile app :)

Comment: That's why I thought prefering the Google App Script would be a solution because I read there won't be any "...loading", it would be lighter, I would be able to get the info once every day instead of all the time with IMPORTXML etc.
And because it seems so easy to display the main image when you hover the link preview... I thought it would be sweet to get this Image so easily displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, Apps Script can't be a solution as it doesn't run on mobile apps. I see that I missed that on your original post.

Comment: Hi @Jescanellas we didn't understand each other : I don't want to use App Script on mobile. I want : (1) to get an image from a link preview of a blog post (to be able to use it with a link blogpost from a RSS Feed (2) I want it to be in Google Sheets (3) I thing the solution is with App Script since no Formula seems to be efficient (4) Afterwards, from this Google Sheet, I will be able to display it on my mobile from a mobile app I am able to build with https://www.glideapps.com/ (this part Google Sheet --> Glide is working, I am asking for the previous part Google Sheet with App Script).